# CTRL-Drag does not copy form controls in EXCEL 2010

Tags: excel

I have an EXCEL sheet containing VBA controls.  When I CTRL-drag the sheet to copy it, the copy contains the VBA controls of the original.  However, when my colleague does this, her copy does not contain the VBA controls.  We are both running Office 2010, both under Win 7 64-bit and we both have the Developer tool bar on the Office ribbon.  All suggestions gratefully received

Thanks!

Alun G

Comment: File > Options > Advanced -> https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Advanced-options-33244b32-fe79-4579-91a6-48b3be0377c4 -> Cut, Copy, and Paste -> Cut, copy, and sort inserted objects with their parent cells

Comment: Thanks!  That solved the problem!!